# need advice on refactoring a large java switch-case

Tags: java, switch-statement, refactoring

I have this large switch case that I really don't like, but I don't seem to find an elegant replacement solution. 
We are building a JavaEE platform where users can create Projects. The method listed is used for determining a status message that is displayed to our users, which depends on many factors, such as the user type (we have 2), the project state, the payment state of the project and many more. Most of these factors have to be determined programmatically, which ended up in having this large switch-case:

```
public List<String> getToDoMessages(Project project) {
    UserAccount user = securitySession.getLoggedInAccount();
    switch (user.getAccountType()) {
        case EXPERT:
            return getExpertToDoMessages(project, user);
        case COMPANY:
            return getCompanyToDoMessages(project, user);
        default:
            return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

private List<String> getCompanyToDoMessages(Project project, UserAccount user) {
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (project.getProjectState()) {
        case OPEN_FOR_APPLICATION:
            ret.add("projectToDo_company_applicationDeadlineNotPassed");
            break;
        case SELECT_APPLICATION:
            ret.add("projectToDo_company_selectApplicant");
            break;
        case IN_PROGRESS:
            ret.add("projectToDo_company_inProgress");
            break;
        case TEAM_PAYMENT_DISTRIBUTION:
            ret.add("projectToDo_company_teamPaymentDistribution");
            break;
        case CONFIRM_INVOICES:
            if (projectAssessmentService.hasAssessed(user, project)) {
                ret.add("projectToDo_company_confirmInvoices");
            } else {
                ret.add("projectToDo_company_assessProject");
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return ret;
}

private List<String> getExpertToDoMessages(Project project, UserAccount user) {
    ExpertPerson expert = securitySession.getExpert();
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (project.getProjectState()) {
        case OPEN_FOR_APPLICATION:
            if (projectService.hasAlreadyApplied(expert, project)) {
                if (projectService.hasAlreadyAppliedAsPerson(expert, project)) {
                    ret.add("projectToDo_expert_appliedAsSinglePerson");
                }
                if (projectService.hasAlreadyAppliedAsTeam(expert, project)) {
                    ret.add("projectToDo_expert_appliedAsTeam");
                }

            } else {
                if (projectService.canApply(expert, project)) {
                    ret.add("projectToDo_expert_openForApplication");
                }
            }
            break;
        case SELECT_APPLICATION:
            ret.add("projectToDo_expert_selectApplicant");
            break;
        case IN_PROGRESS:
            ret.add("projectToDo_expert_inProgress");
            break;
        case TEAM_PAYMENT_DISTRIBUTION:
            Application application = project.getSelectedApplication();
            if (application.isSingleApplication()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal state TEAM_PAYMENT_DISTRIBUTION for project that has selected a single application");
            }
            ExpertTeam team = application.getExpertTeam();
            if (team.getLeader().equals(expert)) {
                ret.add("projectToDo_expert_teamLeaderPaymentDistribution");
            } else {
                ret.add("projectToDo_expert_teamMemberPaymentDistribution");
            }
            break;
        case CONFIRM_INVOICES:
            if (projectAssessmentService.hasAssessed(user, project)) {
                ret.add("projectToDo_expert_confirmInvoices");
            } else {
                ret.add("projectToDo_expert_assessProject");
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This version doesn't have all possibilities listed, the distinction of the project type for example is still missing. Of course, I could at least move the code inside the statements into separate methods, but I'm sure there has to be a more elegant solution. Does anyone know a good pattern that might be applicable here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use polymorphism instead of switch

Comment: That's rather difficult in our situation, we can't move this method into any entity class as we need dependency injection for some of the distinctions. Also, that would probably only solve one level of switch-case (which of course is better than nothing)

Comment: Are you allowed to edit the enum classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three good routes to take for refactoring `switch` statements.

1. Use a `Map`. This allows you to pre-build the tooling and can often even allow you to configure the tooling from external configuration files. Downsides here are that you have to jump through some hoops to add logic.
2. Use an `enum`. This can be more flexible than a `Map` because you can code logic inside each `enum` but there are some downsides. Some feel that coding logic in an `enum` is a bad thing (I do not). Also, the fact that `enum`s can only be `static` can make you work a little less easy.
3. Use polymorphism. Make your `Project` object have a `getToDoMessages` method etc. This can lead to some quite complex management issues as all of the `getToDoMessages` methods are distributed throughout your code rather than in one module as you have them now - but please consider this option as a good one as it is often the most flexible one.

Example of the `Map` route:

```
Map<Integer,String> companyToDos = new HashMap<>();
static {
    companyToDos.put(OPEN_FOR_APPLICATION, "projectToDo_company_applicationDeadlineNotPassed");
    companyToDos.put(SELECT_APPLICATION, "projectToDo_company_selectApplicant");
    companyToDos.put(IN_PROGRESS, "projectToDo_company_inProgress");
    companyToDos.put(TEAM_PAYMENT_DISTRIBUTION, "projectToDo_company_teamPaymentDistribution");
    companyToDos.put(CONFIRM_INVOICES_ASSESSED, "projectToDo_company_confirmInvoices");
    companyToDos.put(CONFIRM_INVOICES_UNASSESSED, "projectToDo_company_assessProject");
}
```

Example of taking the `enum` route:

```
enum AccountType {
    EXPERT{

        @Override
        List<String> getToDoMessages(Project project) {
            return project.getState().getExpertToDoMessages();
        }

    },
    COMPANY{

        @Override
        List<String> getToDoMessages(Project project) {
            return project.getState().getCompanyToDoMessages();
        }

    };

    abstract List<String> getToDoMessages(Project project);

}

enum ProjectState {
    OPEN_FOR_APPLICATION{

        @Override
        List<String> getExpertToDoMessages(Project project) {
            return ...
        }

        @Override
        List<String> getCompanyToDoMessages(Project project) {
            return ...
        }

    },
    SELECT_APPLICATION{

        @Override
        List<String> getExpertToDoMessages(Project project) {
            return ...
        }

        @Override
        List<String> getCompanyToDoMessages(Project project) {
            return ...
        }

    };

    abstract List<String> getExpertToDoMessages(Project project);
    abstract List<String> getCompanyToDoMessages(Project project);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great examples! I looked through all cases and for 95% of them, the enum-route would be an alternative. However, we still have some logic that cannot be placed inside either the enum or entity classes and require Injection. Therefore, i will leave the current state for now, as this also prevents cluttering the enums. This way, we still have a mess, but it is restricted to one model, which is acceptable from my point of view, as the enums already are quite blown-up (not all states are listed in this example)